# lifetime of constant variable?

Tags: runtime, constants, microcontroller, lifetime

what is the lifetime of constant variables in microcontroller ?
Is the const variables allocated before Runtime or during Runtime ?

```
void main()
{ 
  const x=5;
  while(1)
  { }

}
```

Comment: it can depend on the compiler and compiler flags.  your example code is dead code so no constant will be allocated at all since it does nothing (if you use optimizations).  there is no one fixed answer because the spec does not dictate this sort of thing, nor should it.

Comment: for your particular target with your specific compiler with your favorite options, compile then disassemble to see what happened.  that is the only answer.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the compiler.

Usually constant are placed in program memory. After compiling is done constants are built in in HEX file.

For example Microchip C18 and XC32 compilers has different handling. While C18 has const ROM with C32 you have to use `-membedded-data` flag to specify how and were in ROM constants will be placed.

Comment: I mean when you burn the code on the target .. as the role of the compiler ended after bringing the final file(.elf).

Comment: Consts are always stored in ROM (program memory). Which means embedded into your HEX file (you can search for them). Memory space allocation is done during compiling/linking process what is probably answer to your question. What I meant is that in some cases, depending on platform you can "tweak" a compiler to set exact ROM area for constants. For example C18 compiler allows to specify storage qualifiers such are ```near``` or ```far``` for any constant that you declare. This way you can make better organisation of program memory and keep often used constants in near segmet for example.